# Simple lightbox for my flex gallery

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox, gallery, lightbox

I have made a flex gallery with a bunch of photos in it, what I want to do is make a simple lightbox (I thibk thats the term) where when an image is clicked it will be displayed bigger. No need for next or prev buttons.

I would like to do this with jquery but bear in mind my js skills are that from a complete newbie , thanks in advance!

```css
.photogallery__maincontainer{  width:1300px; height:580px; ; flex:0 0 auto; display:flex; flex-flow:row; flex-wrap:wrap; justify-content:flex-start;}

.photogallery__viewer{ width:55%; height:100%; position:relative; display:flex; }

.photogallery__viewer__image{max-width:80%; height:auto; margin:auto; overflow:hidden;}

.photogallery{
 
 width:42%; 
 height:93%; 
 position:relative; 
 display:flex; 
 flex-wrap:wrap; 
 justify-content:flex-start; 
 align-content:flex-start; 
 overflow:auto;
 
}


.photogallery__image{
 background-image: url('images/20170819_194526.jpg'); 
 background-position: center;  
 background-repeat: no-repeat; 
 background-size:contain; 
 max-height:20%;  
 min-height:20%; 
 flex:0 0 calc(25% - 15px);  
 margin-right:15px; 
 margin-bottom:35px; 
 cursor:pointer;
}

.photogallery__image:hover{
 opacity:0.8;
}

.close{width:3%; cursor:pointer; color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif; flex:0 0 3%; text-align:center; display:table;  font-size:25px; font-weight:600; }

.close:hover{color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);}
```

```html
<div class="photogallery__maincontainer" style="">
  <span style="display:none; cursor:pointer; color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif; font-size:50px; font-weight:600; position:absolute; bottom:5px; right:320px;">&#129087;</span>
  
    <div class="photogallery__viewer" style="">
   <img class="photogallery__viewer__image" src="images/IMG-20170610-WA0025.jpg" style="">
 </div>
 <div class="photogallery" style="">
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/IMG-20170610-WA0025.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/20170819_194526.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/IMG-20170610-WA0040.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/IMG-20170902-WA0031.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/IMG-20170516-WA0023.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/IMG-20170610-WA0017.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/20170812_181516.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/20170822_011703.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/20170815_203103.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/IMG-20170516-WA0011.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/IMG-20170610-WA0030.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/IMG-20170610-WA0047.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/IMG-20170610-WA0038.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/IMG-20170829-WA0017.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/IMG-20170610-WA0019.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/IMG-20170430-WA0022.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/IMG-20170527-WA0002.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/IMG_20170823_222106_761.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/20170811_182103.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/20170522_124602.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/20170522_112958.jpg');"></div>
      <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/');"></div>
   <div class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/');"></div>
   <div id="last" class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/');"></div>
  </div>
  <span class="close" style="">X</span>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: This question is way too broad and therefore off topic for the site, if you are going to do this yourself rather than use a plugin, then you will need to make an attempt and then when you get stuck with a specific problem, come back and post code and ask a question relating to the problem.  Other than that, if you are a complete newb, then I would suggest using a plugin or at least downloading one and seeing how they implement their lightbox and try to copy it

Comment: you should give it a try and post a specific problem when you have one. Just a little advice, when i had to do this, i actually stored the images ratio because you might want to display them differently if portrait or landscape. It was at the beginning of CSS3 when i did that, maybe there are CSS rules now, but just in case

Comment: First, lightbox scripts usually use links to get source of bigger image. And I think that fancyBox3 would be the easiest one to use - just add two files and then add `data-fancybox` attribute to your links.